# Re-sizing google charts with fluid bootstrap layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am using [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) with twitter bootstrap in rails application.

In fluid layout if the span width decreases, the chart overflows its parent div.

Can google chart width be given in percentages?

Please help.

**Update**

I am using [google_visualr](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr) gem.

Here is my controller code.

```
def home

  # Indents
  indent_status_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
  indent_status_table.new_column('string', 'STATUS')
  indent_status_table.new_column('number', 'COUNT')
  indent_status_table.add_rows(1)
  indent_status_table.set_cell(0, 0, 'Open')
  indent_status_table.set_cell(0, 1, 100)

  opts   = { :title => 'INDENT STATUS', :is3D => true }
  @indent_status_chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::PieChart.new(indent_status_table, opts)

end
```

And here is my html.erb code

```
<div id='shipment_status_chart' style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
<%= render_chart @shipment_status_chart, 'shipment_status_chart' %>
```

And in java script code.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function(){
    drawChart();
  });   

});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the chart width in the HTML

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
```

From Google Charts documentation:

> **Specifying the size in HTML** - A chart can take a few seconds to load
>   and render. If you have the chart container already sized in HTML, the
>   page layout won't jump around when the chart is loaded.

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/Qquse/208/) showing 100% width.

**Update**
To resize the chart when the window changes size, you can use jQuery to update the chart size.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        drawChart();
    });
});
```

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/Qquse/211/) showing 100% width with update on screen resize.

Comment: It's working pretty fine. But when we re-size the window we need to refresh the page. Can we do something about it too?

Comment: The update part doesn't seems to be working. Will it redraw all charts in the page?

Comment: It will run the `drawChart()` function. So yours might be called something else. If you post your javascript I would be able to give a more precise answer.

Comment: Ok this gem isn't supporting redrawing as of now. 
https://github.com/winston/google_visualr/pull/45

Comment: Here is a hack using `.load()` see here http://fiddle.jshell.net/doitlikejustin/Qquse/217/show/ using `$('html').load(window.location);` as it basically just refreshes the page content

Comment: redraw the graph on the resize event seems really overkilling since drawing a graph could be really heavy and the resize event is triggered many many times a second. A timer would be a good option to improve that. It's still a good start through ;)

Comment: This only works for me on resize, not on page load.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google Charts with [ng-google-chart.js](https://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart) and in order to make my charts responsive I've added `style="max-width:100%"`

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div google-chart style="max-width:100%" chart="chart"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div google-chart style="max-width:100%" chart="chart"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div google-chart style="max-width:100%" chart="chart"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div google-chart style="max-width:100%" chart="chart"/>
  </div>
</div>
```